# Scrolling background image cut in half - cocos2d

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm making a game that has a background image that was too big for the iphone's to render. So I had to cut it in half. Since my background is scrolling horizontally (like in [JetPack Joyride](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/jetpack-joyride/id457446957?mt=8)), I want to make it so that the halves come together to make it look like one image. So what I tried to do was, position the first half of the image on the far left of the screen, and then I tried to position the second one on the edge of the 1st one. This is what I tried so far.

in the `init`:

```
        numStripes = 1;

        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < numStripes; i++)
        {
        CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bg0.png"];
        CCSprite *sprite2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bg1.png"];

        sprite.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5f);
        sprite.position = CGPointMake(0, screenSize.height / 2);

        sprite2.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5f);
        sprite2.position = CGPointMake(sprite.position.x + sprite.contentSize.width, screenSize.height / 2);

        [backgroundNode addChild:sprite z:i tag:i];
        [backgroundNode addChild:sprite2 z:i tag:i];
        }

        // endless scrolling
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < numStripes; i++)
        {
        CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bg0.png"];
        CCSprite *sprite2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bg1.png"];
        sprite.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5f);
        sprite2.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5f);
        sprite.position = CGPointMake(sprite.contentSize.width + sprite2.contentSize.width - 1, screenSize.height / 2);
        sprite2.position = CGPointMake(sprite.contentSize.width * 2.0f + sprite2.contentSize.width - 1.0f, screenSize.height / 2);

        [backgroundNode addChild:sprite z:i tag:i + 2];
        [backgroundNode addChild:sprite2 z:i tag:i + 2];
        }

        speedFactors = [[CCArray alloc] initWithCapacity:numStripes];
        [speedFactors addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f]];
        NSAssert([speedFactors count] == numStripes, @"speedFactors count does not match numStripes!");
```

This could be the problem:

```
-(void) dealloc
{
#ifndef KK_ARC_ENABLED
    [speedFactors release];
    [super dealloc];
#endif // KK_ARC_ENABLED
}

-(void) update:(ccTime)delta
{
    if (([[GameMechanics sharedGameMechanics] gameState] == GameStateRunning) || [[GameMechanics sharedGameMechanics] gameState] == GameStateMenu)
    {
        [self updateRunning:delta];
    }
}

- (void) updateRunning:(ccTime)delta
{
    // read current scroll Speed
    scrollSpeed = [[GameMechanics sharedGameMechanics] backGroundScrollSpeedX];

    CCSprite* sprite;
    // we use a c-array since it is faster on iteration
    CCARRAY_FOREACH([backgroundNode children], sprite)
    {
        // retrieve the scrollspeed factor for the current sprite
        NSNumber* factor = [speedFactors objectAtIndex:sprite.zOrder];

        // move the background layer
        CGPoint pos = sprite.position;
        pos.x -= scrollSpeed * [factor floatValue] * delta;

        // when a layer is off screen on the left side, move it to the right end of the screen
        if (pos.x < -sprite.contentSize.width)
        {
            pos.x += (sprite.contentSize.width * 4) - 1;
        }

        sprite.position = pos;
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to work and I'm getting weird results... Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be this:

```
sprite.position = CGPointMake(0, screenSize.height / 2);
sprite2.position = CGPointMake(sprite.position.x*1.5, screenSize.height / 2);
```

`sprite2`'s initial x value is getting set to 0. What you probably want is:

```
sprite2.position = CGPointMake(sprite.position.x + sprite.contentSize.width, screenSize.height / 2);
```

There's another problem here:

```
sprite.position = CGPointMake(sprite.contentSize.width - 1)*2, screenSize.height / 2);
                sprite2.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5f);
sprite2.position = CGPointMake((sprite2.contentSize.width - 1)*2, screenSize.height / 2);
```

It should probably be:

```
sprite.position = CGPointMake(sprite.contentSize.width + sprite2.contentSize.width - 1, screenSize.height / 2);
sprite2.position = CGPointMake(sprite.contentSize.width * 2.0f + sprite2.contentSize.width - 1.0f, screenSize.height / 2);
```

You probably also have an issue setting the same tag to two different sprites. You're setting tags for both `sprite` and its copy to 0, and tags for both `sprite2` and its copy to 1. You should set the tag for `sprite` to 0, `sprite2` to 1, `sprite` (copy) to 2, and `sprite2` (copy) to 3.

In the second for loop:

```
[backgroundNode addChild:sprite z:i tag:i + 2];
[backgroundNode addChild:sprite2 z:i tag:i + 2];
```

**Updated:**

In your `-updateRunning:` method change this:

```
pos.x += (sprite.contentSize.width * 2) - 2;
```

to this:

```
pos.x += (sprite.contentSize.width * 4) - 1;
```

Because you have four sprites like this:

[1][2][3][4]

when [1] moves offscreen you need to move [1] all the way behind [4] so that they're like this

[2][3][4][1]

which is why you need the move [1] four lengths to the right and not two lengths to the right.

**Updated:**

It doesn't look like you have enough speedFactors. It looks like you are adding one value to the speedFactors array, but later trying to get two of them. You don't need different speed factors until you add parallax scrolling, so for now change:

```
NSNumber* factor = [speedFactors objectAtIndex:sprite.zOrder];
```

to

```
NSNumber* factor = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
```

Comment: This almost worked, I still get some funky outputs though... I've updated my question, I think that is what is contributing to the weird output...

Comment: Both of the backgrounds are loading, but they are being placed in different positions every time the background loops. The bg's aren't being placed in the "one after another" way

Comment: This made it work for the first loop, but then after that, it went back to being placed in a different position each time... I updated the code in my question to match what i have on my game.

Comment: Ok, updated again. Can you let me know what you see after making that fix?

Comment: It works for 2 loops, and then everything gets screwed up again: the images start overlaying each other, they appear out of order, there are gaps (black screen) after the 2nd loop.

Comment: Are the images moving at different speeds or is it just that their positions are not correct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45527/discussion-between-shalin-shah-and-joseph-chen)